# How to build Ionic Cordova with Xcode 10?

Tags: ionic-framework, xcode10, ionic4

I would try:

ionic cordova build ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please describe more your problem with error messages and giving output of `ionic info`. ionic 3 can work already with xcode 10.

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect your iphone and wait that it's detected on Xcode. Then you can select it and run your app from Xcode.